# Inheritance Method in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, built-in

Is there a method in python that will trigger when class was inherited?

```py
class Base:
  __inherit__( cls ):
    cls.bar += 'World!'

class Foo( Base ):
  bar = 'Hello, '

Foo.bar # 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: I think you want `__new__`

Comment: `__new__` will be executed when a class instance is created, not when it is subclassed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `__init_subclass__`:

```
class Base:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.bar += "World"

class Foo(Base):
    bar = 'Hello, '

print(Foo.bar)
```

Output:

```
Hello, World
```